# Docker: cannot access the folder structure of based image

Tags: docker

I have this image:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.3

# copy db project to container
ADD . /db_project

WORKDIR /db_project

CMD ["./gitinitall.sh"]
```

This will copy the content of the current dir with db project that it contains git submodules which will be checked out and pulled from repo. So in db_project is the shell script that I run to get the submodules. Also has the backend that uses the dbs. The image is pushed to a private repo.

I want to use this image to create a container where I need to add the config of the database for the environment where it needs to be deployed, something like:

```
FROM myprivatedockerrepo:5000/db_project
...
WORKDIR /db_project
COPY config/dev.config /db_project/apps/mydb_db/config/dev.config

# get everything needed for backend
RUN mix deps.get

# expose the backend port
EXPOSE backendport

# start the beckend with the proper db configured
CMD ["./startbeckend"]
```

But it is failing to RUN mix deps.get:

```
Step 14/20 : RUN mix deps.get
---> Running in ab7375d69989
warning: path "apps/mydb_db" is a directory but it has no mix.exs. Mix won't consider this directory as part of your umbrella application. Please add a "mix.exs" or set the ":apps" key in your umbrella configuration with all relevant apps names as atoms
```

If I add a

```
RUN ls apps/mydb_db
```

before running the mix command:

```
ls: cannot access apps/mydb_db: No such file or directory
```

So it seems although in the image used, myprivatedockerrepo:5000/db_project, there should be 
db_project/apps/mydb_db - mydb_db created by the shell script submodule get from git, it cannot find it, maybe I do not understand the docker layers or something?

Comment: You can debug this kind of thing by commenting out the broken lines, and then running e.g. `docker run -it <image_name> /bin/sh`.

Comment: Very hard to find a solution to your problem without knowing what's in your project dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my bad,
the gitinitall.sh script to get and update all submodules from git didn't work, since had no git settings or ssh key in the image, but it didn't return any code so it shows no failure.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a folder you need to add a final '/'

# Dockerfile
 ADD . /db_project/

See also here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Comment: Yeah, that's right, OP use COPY instead, is better! with COPY no final slash needed :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but if I add RUN ls /db_project I get all the project structure where the folder apps is also there but is empty ...

Comment: I just ran into this same issue using COPY. If I don't include the enclosing "/app/", then it doesn't work.